# Mixed Content issue after clear Laravel cache

Tags: laravel, mixed-content

A Laravel project was running without any issues in my development Server(secured-https). With my new release, new config in **.env** file was not loaded. Then I found some solutions in StackOverflow which said to clear Laravel config and cache.
So I run the following commands,

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan config:cache`

`php artisan config:clear`

After cache is cleared with above commands, it is not loading stylesheets and js files properly, and says **"Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."**.

If it is something with file requiring, how it was working fine initially? What is the solution to bring it back to previous state?

Comment: Have you made out which resource is being loaded via http? Is it an image, css or a script? Is your `APP_URL` set to https in your `.env`?

Comment: All the css and scripts files are loaded internally and all of them are not getting loaded. But internal images are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

> wanted to write this as a comment but requires 50 reputations.

You can check if there is an external file called inside your CSS and js files.
and you have already hosted it then you can check your mixed content using various online tools, some of them gives detailed information which file is causing the error

Comment: All the files are loaded internally and all of them are not getting loaded

Answer (score 0):

Some css/js/image file is calling over http. This mixed content error is for that only

Or you can force all your url by adding

```
$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS','on');
```

in your boot method of AppServiceProvider